# Styling the element in separate component using conditions in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom

In my react app I have a hidden banner that I want to show, when the length of the array reaches to 5. But it looks like that I am trying to get an element before it is rendered. I get the error about getting a style of undefined element.

This function must change css of the banner element and make it visible.

```
  showBanner() {
            let banner = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay')[0]
            banner.style.cssText = "visibility: visible;opacity: 1;"
        }
```

I want to render my popup component only if the condition is met.

```
render() {
        if (this.props.awarded) {
            if (this.props.awarded.length === 5) {
                this.showBanner()
                return (
                    <>
                        <h1 id="awardLabel">5 movies</h1>
                        <div id="movieList">
                            {this.props.awarded.map((movie) => {
                                return (
                                    <div className="awardHolder" key={movie.imdbID}>
                                        <div className="awardImgHolder"  >
                                            <img src={movie.Poster} alt={movie.Title}></img>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="awardMovieInfo">
                                            <p>{movie.Title}</p>
                                            <p>year {movie.Year}</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="withdrawButton" onClick={(e) => this.deleteMovie(e, movie)}> WITHDRAW </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })}
                        </div>
                        <Popup />
                    </>
                )
            } else { ...
```

This is my banner structure.

```
<div id="popup1" className="overlay">
                <div className="popup">
                    <h2>Here i am</h2>
                    <a className="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                    <div className="content">
                        <p>Congratulations. You've nominated 5 movies.</p>
                        <button onClick={this.closeBanner}>Try again</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is my css for the banner element.

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

How can I dynamically change element's styles using conditions to render that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access your `Popup` component before it gets created. In other words, `this.showBanner()` is called before `<Popup />` is rendered.

One solution is to move your popup to a higher-level component

Comment: Moving it to a higher-level component helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good use case for [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), which will allow you to have some global state that your components can tap into without having to pass the banner state through multiple components as props.

If you are going to do this, you might consider not manually updating the styling with querySelectors; instead, you can have React either render or not render the component based on your global banner state.

Your application will be wrapped in <BannerContext.Provider> tags, and then the component that needs to render or not render the banner can use <BannerContext.Consumer> tags to check the current banner state. You can also store a toggle function in the BannerContext so that other parts of the application (and the banner itself) can toggle the BannerContext as needed.

Comment: Thank you. @hellojeffhall I just looked at the context, but it looks like an overkill for this task since only one component needs to know about the banner to be able to render it. Is there another way to accomplish same task?

Comment: @ViacheslavNazarenko it's a little bit hard to say without knowing how your code is structured. Where does the banner live relative to your other components? Some parent component could have some `isBannerOpen` state and a `toggleBanner` function that wraps around setState, and use props to pass `toggleBanner` to the components that need it, and use `isBannerOpen` to tell whether or not to render the banner. But if this will involve passing props through many levels of components then something like the Context API is a good idea--"prop drilling" is considered bad practice.